やるからには instead of やるには here?

でも喧嘩するのは損じゃないですか！ ここは一発、編集長好みの売れそうなキャッチーな企画当ててやりましょうよ！ やっぱやりたいことをやるからには実績作ってからじゃないと。 (YouTube clip)

The clip should contain sufficient information that makes the context clear enough. The speaker suggests a compromise: instead of doing a project which the speaker and the listener both would like to do but has been dismissed by 編集長, they do another project that caters to 編集長's liking. And in this specific context 「からには」 doesn't sound the most natural to me because 「からには」 means 「前件が成立することにより、当然後件の事態が成り立つという、強い因果関係を表わす。」 (source) as in for example: 「やるからにはちゃんとしないと！」. But here 「やるには実績作ってからじゃないと」 seems to fit the context so much better. "In order to do the stuff we want to do, we need to..."

There is no difference in からには's usage between "やりたいことをやるからには実績作ってからじゃないと" and "やるからにはちゃんとしないと".

「XからにはY」「X以上(は)Y」の形で、Xを理由として取りたてる表現である。Xの成立が決定的なので、その上でとるべき態度や心構え(Y)を述べるもの

A verbose translation of "やるからにはちゃんとしないと" would be something like "Since/If you've decided to do it, naturally, you need to do it right". Similarly, "やりたいことをやるからには実績作ってからじゃないと" roughly means "Since/If you've decided to do what you want, naturally, you need to do it after building up achievements".
"やりたいことをやるには実績作ってからじゃないと" (without から) also makes perfect sense in this context, but in the original sentence, やりたいことをやる is not a purpose but a decided plan.
